# Each loop in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, each

So I have this following request:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "student_work"=>{"work_experiences_attributes"=>{"1415498778636"=>{"company_name"=>"Company1",
 "start_year"=>"2014",
 "end_year"=>"2014",
 "job_title"=>"Title1",
 "job_description"=>"test1"},
 "1415498795509"=>{"company_name"=>"Company2",
 "start_year"=>"2014",
 "end_year"=>"2014",
 "job_title"=>"Title2",
 "job_description"=>"Test2"}}},
 "commit"=>"Next"}
```

or to make it easier:

```
student_work[work_experiences_attributes][1415498778636][company_name]:Company1
student_work[work_experiences_attributes][1415498778636][start_year]:1
student_work[work_experiences_attributes][1415498778636][start_year]:2014
student_work[work_experiences_attributes][1415498778636][end_year]:2
student_work[work_experiences_attributes][1415498778636][end_year]:2014
student_work[work_experiences_attributes][1415498778636][job_title]:Title1
student_work[work_experiences_attributes][1415498778636][job_description]:test1
student_work[work_experiences_attributes][1415498795509][company_name]:Company2
student_work[work_experiences_attributes][1415498795509][start_year]:3
student_work[work_experiences_attributes][1415498795509][start_year]:2014
student_work[work_experiences_attributes][1415498795509][end_year]:4
student_work[work_experiences_attributes][1415498795509][end_year]:2014
student_work[work_experiences_attributes][1415498795509][job_title]:Title2
student_work[work_experiences_attributes][1415498795509][job_description]:Test2
```

How do I access each values using the each loop in Ruby? I am still new to Ruby, please help. Thanks

**Update**
Those number (1415498778636 and 1415498795509) is always changing, so the loop must be able to handle any different kind of numbers

Comment: In future, please simplify your example as much as possible. Here, for example, there are many key-value pairs that could be removed without making the example less meaningful. Also, shortening names makes it more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
params['student_work']['work_experiences_attributes'].values.each do |hash|
  hash.each do |key, value|
    # ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually as `student_work[work_experiences_attributes]` is a Hash, so you can just use `each` method.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Hash.html#method-i-each

Answer (score 0):

You mean response instead request right?
You could do:

```
attr=params[:student_work].keys.each do |key|
    key.to_i > 0
end[0] 
params[:student_work][attr].each do |key, value|
# do something
end
```

Comment: Ok. The width is fixed?